# Removing group type GLTF object from the scene in THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to remove a group of object from the scene, `scene.remove(group)` didn't work.

this is my loader:

```
GLTFloader.load( src+'.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if(child.type === "Group")
                    {
                        newObject = true;
                        GLTFobjects.push(child);
                    }
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.material.transparent = true;
                        child.material.opacity = 0.7;
                    }
                } );
                scene.add( gltf.scene );

            },function ( xhr ) {

                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

            },
            // called when loading has errors
            function ( error ) {

                console.log( 'An error happened' );
                console.log(error);

            }
        );
```

**GLTFobjects** is the global array that have all my objects.

every member of the GLTFobjects is group type, Let's say that the first element of this array should be removed.

I've tried the following:

```
scene.remove(GLTFobjects[0])
```

and:

```
GLTFobjects.children.forEach(function (value,index) {
                    scene.remove(value);
                });
```

or even:

```
GLTFobjects[0].traverse(function (e) {
                        scene.remove(e);
                    });
```

Nothing has worked.

How to remove group object from the scene ?

Note:
`GLTFobjects[0]` look like this (if it make any help):

```
{…}​castShadow: false​children: Array(7) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]​frustumCulled: true​id: 24​layers: Object { mask: 1 }​matrix: Object { elements: (16) […] }​matrixAutoUpdate: true​matrixWorld: Object { elements: (16) […] }​matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false​modelViewMatrix: Object { elements: (16) […] }​name: "House3"​normalMatrix: Object { elements: (9) […] }​parent: Object { uuid: "E6BE42B7-C7D3-4617-83E5-83EACD0948B6", name: "Scene", type: "Scene", … }​position: Object { x: 0, y: 1.1222255229949951, z: -16.519949752598595 }​quaternion: Object { _x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, … }​receiveShadow: false​renderOrder: 0​rotation: Object { _x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, … }​scale: Object { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 }​type: "Group"​up: Object { x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 }​userData: Object {  }​uuid: "9F7508DD-E1C2-481D-AF49-57EE3973C27F"​visible: true​<prototype>: Object { constructor: Group(), isGroup: true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gltf.scene` was added into the `scene` instead of your `GLTFobjects` group.

If you have added the `GLTFobjects`, you could simply do:

> GLTFobjects.remove(GLTFobjects.getObjectByName("cube"));

or

> GLTFobjects.remove(GLTFobjects.children[0]);